# how to split some json arrays in one variable into different variables? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split

I'm confused about JSON.

I got this JSON data (already parsed) from php;

```
    var json =
    {"id":"1", "name":"AAA", "sex":"m", "age":"20", "region":"X"}
    {"id":"2", "name":"BBB", "sex":"m", "age":"25", "region":"Y"}
    {"id":"3", "name":"CCC", "sex":"f", "age":"30", "region":"Z"}
    {"id":"4", "name":"DDD", "sex":"m", "age":"35", "region":"Q"}
```

and these are separated arrays within one var.

I'd like to make them like this,

```
    var json1 = {"id":"1", "name":"AAA", "sex":"m", "age":"20", "region":"X"}
    var json2 = {"id":"2", "name":"BBB", "sex":"m", "age":"25", "region":"Y"}
    var json3 = {"id":"3", "name":"CCC", "sex":"f", "age":"30", "region":"Z"}
    var json4 = {"id":"4", "name":"DDD", "sex":"m", "age":"35", "region":"Q"}
```

---

I'm currently developing Titanium mobile (iOS) with PHP.
and PHP send JSON data like this;

```
    foreach($responses as $response)
    {
        echo encode_json($response);
    }
```

※$responses is result from sql order.

and now Titanium side, Titanium file will receive and parse it.

```
    Req.onload = function()
    {
        var json = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
        var response = JSON.parse(json);
        Ti.API.info(response);
    }
```

Ti.API.info says on console;

```
    [INFO] {"id":"1", "name":"AAA", "sex":"m", "age":"20", "region":"X"}{"id":"2", "name":"BBB", "sex":"m", "age":"25", "region":"Y"}{"id":"3", "name":"CCC", "sex":"f", "age":"30", "region":"Z"}{"id":"4", "name":"DDD", "sex":"m", "age":"35", "region":"Q"}
    //as I wrote it above
```

I'm sorry for those came to see JS problem but Titanium.

Comment: How exactly is the variable `json` defined? Because how you wrote it is not valid.

Comment: thx pointing, I added some details.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
var json =
    {"id":"1", "name":"AAA", "sex":"m", "age":"20", "region":"X"}
    {"id":"2", "name":"BBB", "sex":"m", "age":"25", "region":"Y"}
    {"id":"3", "name":"CCC", "sex":"f", "age":"30", "region":"Z"}
    {"id":"4", "name":"DDD", "sex":"m", "age":"35", "region":"Q"}

var json1 = json[0];
var json2 = json[1];
var json3 = json[2];
var json4 = json[3];
```

Comment: @user1258134 If this answer helped please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your first json  is actually an array like this :

```
var json = [
    {"id":"1", "name":"AAA", "sex":"m", "age":"20", "region":"X"},
    {"id":"2", "name":"BBB", "sex":"m", "age":"25", "region":"Y"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"CCC", "sex":"f", "age":"30", "region":"Z"},
    {"id":"4", "name":"DDD", "sex":"m", "age":"35", "region":"Q"}
];
```

Then you could split the array into individual variables like this :

```
for(var i=0,l=json.length;i<l;i++)
    window['json' + (i+1)] = json[i];
```

Note that declaring a variable in the global scope (like `var foo = 'bar'`) can be done by attaching that name to the window object (`window['foo'] = 'bar';`);